# flutter doctor --android-licenses gives a java error in windows 10

Tags: java, android, flutter, android-studio, flutter-dependencies

I came Up with this error and my Android SDK Command-line tools are already installed in my android studio.[image]

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchema
        at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule$SchemaModuleVersion.<init>(SchemaModule.java:156)
        at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule.<init>(SchemaModule.java:75)
        at com.android.sdklib.repository.AndroidSdkHandler.<clinit>(AndroidSdkHandler.java:81)
        at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:73)
        at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:48)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
```

Comment: did you try `flutter doctor`? or `flutter doctor --android-licenses`?

Comment: What version of java do you have installed? It needs to be version 8 (or 11 may work)

Comment: i have installed jdk version 16.0.2

Comment: Note that Java 11+ **won't** work.  The `javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema` class has been removed from Java SE (it is a separate library now).

Comment: The version of flutter you are trying to use won't work with Java 16.

Comment: See also https://yookoala.medium.com/notes-about-flutter-and-android-studio-installation-on-linux-db9e4b7d0b44.  You need to use the version of Java that is distributed with Android Studio.

Comment: i am using windows os...which version of jdk should i use with flutter version 2.5.0??